# How to make web browser automation tool using Python and Win32

Tags: python, win32com

I'm pretty new about programming and I'm making an web browsing automation tool using Python and Win32. 
What I want to do is input keyword in Google and click search button, but I couldn't click any of them.
Probably I input wrong parameters. Could you please correct me?

I used FindWindowEX but I couldn't get the elements.
Please refer to the attached code.

```
ie = win32com.Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = 1

url = "https://www.google.com"
ie.navigate(url)  

while ie.Busy:
    time.sleep(1)

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("IEFrame", "Google - Internet Explorer")

# Find element handle (Problem)
EditboxHnd= win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0 , "Button" , "gLFyf gsfi")  # To click search edit box of Google, but return value is 0
SearchbtnHnd= win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0 , "Button" , "btnK") # To click search button, but return value is 0

# To click the search button
PostMessage(SearchbtnHnd, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, None, None) 
PostMessage(SearchbtnHnd, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, None, None)
```

I expect the button and edit box's handle to input search keywords and click the search button, but the return values are 0.

P.S: I used Selenium for this, but when I faced a problem that when a button that opened file upload dialog box was clicked, I couldn't control the dialog box. That's why I'm trying to use Win32 api.

Comment: Try looking into selenium to see if it does what you are looking for

Comment: @DanielButler Actually I coded using Selenium before. However I couldn't find the method for controlling child dialog box. (Child window was okay, but child dialog box for file uploading was the problem). I'd love to know how to control it actually :-)

Comment: I missed the last part of your question. You might want to dig into it more. It’s the go to solution for web testing so it might be in a corner that you haven’t explored yet. I wish I could help more.

Comment: @DanielButler It can be. Thank you anyway!